# IE10 + 11: onscroll & transform laggy performance

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, internet-explorer

I have a simple snippet to create a "fixed header" with JS and CSS transforms. Performance is great on modern browsers but it jumps on IE 10 & 11.

I'm not sure if it's IE's scroll event that is slow or the style change.

Is there a workaround to get performance up?

or do i need to go down a different path? (`position:fixed`) - i would really hate to go down the position fixed path as translateY solution works great with table headers as well.

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');

window.onscroll = function() {
  var wintop = window.pageYOffset;
  var offset = el.offsetTop;
  el.style.transform = 'translateY(' + (window.pageYOffset - el.offsetTop) + 'px)';
};
```

Try is out [here](http://codepen.io/Facius/pen/JKvLRP).

Answer (score 0):

The `scroll` event is fired too many times and that can be a reason of the performance lag you encountered in IE.

I'd suggest using [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce), [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) or implementing your own solution using timeouts to control how many times you allow a function to be executed over time.

Read [the article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, throttling or debouncing doesn't seem to do any difference in this case. I've updated the codepen with both throttle and debounce functions

Comment: @Facius It turns out, you have to use `position: fixed`. By the way, it doesn't require any JS and more performant.

Comment: Thanks, I know that is a possible solution for a "simple sticky header". But it doesn't work well if you need to have a sticky header on a dynamic table (width of the columns get screwed). 
The example i have provided is an extremely simplified version, the real solution is much larger and very flexible.